# Delete empty Folders (recursion)

Tags: vb.net, recursion

Why is my code not working? It should check every folder for other files/directorys and then delete it.

```
Private Sub DeleteEmptyFolder(ByVal sDirectoryPath As String)
    If Owner.PluginXML.EmptyFolder Then
        Try
            If IO.Directory.Exists(sDirectoryPath) Then
                Dim oDirectory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(sDirectoryPath)
                If oDirectory.GetDirectories.Count = 0 AndAlso oDirectory.GetFiles.Count = 0 Then
                    For Each oDir As IO.DirectoryInfo In oDirectory.GetDirectories
                        Log(oDir.Name)  '''Using Log for testing instead of oDir.Delete(True) 
                    Next
                    For Each folder As IO.DirectoryInfo In oDirectory.GetDirectories()
                        DeleteEmptyFolder(folder.FullName)
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Log("Error DeleteEmptyFolder.", LogLevel.Exception, ex)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

There is no error, it just doesn't work/logs empty folders.

Comment: What is the error? Maybe "Collection was modified, enumeration operation may not execute.." ? Not sure, but it seems that you cannot delete folders inside foreach. Maybe get folderpaths-to-be-deleted to list and delete later?

Comment: There is no error. It just doesnt Log/Delete any files.

Comment: In case of empty directory, you never go to Delete/Log because it is inside enumeration (which yields no results since GetDirectories returns nothing) ?

Comment: I proposed new version for your algorithm as an answer..

Comment: If you're asking us that question then you clearly haven't debugged your code. If you had then you'd be able to explain exactly where and how the behaviour differs from your expectation, not just that it "doesn't work" which never an acceptable explanation. You're a developer, not a user, so use the development tools at your fingertips. That's why you're using an IDE instead of a text editor.

Comment: That's right, I have over 30,000 reputation points by only nagging. I understand that people are just starting out with programming and are still learning to write better questions. That's why I tell them how to write better questions. Do you think that it will just happen by magic and the rest of us should just put up with the bad questions in the mean time? How about, instead of taking everything personally, you assume that a criticism of your question is a criticism of your question, consider the reason for the criticism and address it next time. I don't criticise good questions.

Comment: @jmcilhinney well next time try to provide information then

Comment: @jmcilhinney sure bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of empty directory, you never reach Delete/Log because it is inside enumeration (which yields no results since `GetDirectories` returns nothing). Try this instead:

```
Private Sub DeleteEmptyFolder(ByVal sDirectoryPath As String)
    If Owner.PluginXML.EmptyFolder Then
        Try
            If IO.Directory.Exists(sDirectoryPath) Then
                Dim oDirectory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(sDirectoryPath)
                Dim subDirectories = oDirectory.GetDirectories()
                If subDirectories.Length = 0 AndAlso oDirectory.GetFiles().Length = 0 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleting" + sDirectoryPath)
                    'oDirectory.Delete(True)
                    Return
                End If
                For Each folder As IO.DirectoryInfo In subDirectories
                    DeleteEmptyFolder(folder.FullName)
                Next
            End If


        Catch ex As Exception
            Log("Error DeleteEmptyFolder.", LogLevel.Exception, ex)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard for commenting, I amended answer a little..